# Using a DataGrid in a HeaderPanel

Tags: gwt, uibinder

**Edit**

Since no one has responded to my original question I think it is worthwhile adding a description of *what* I am attempting to accomplish, in addition to the existing description of *how* I have attempted to achieve my goal:

My objective is to create a `DataGrid` that will resize according to any change in size of its container. This is not difficult to do, but I have an additional requirement, which is to have `Panel` widgets above and below the `DataGrid`; these two `Panel` widgets will contain widgets that are fixed in size (e.g., a row of buttons or text input widgets). My expectation was that a `HeaderPanel` would be perfect for this, but this doesn't seem to work (as can be seen in my original question, below). So ... an alternative to my original question ("why doesn't this work") is: what is the best way to implement this requirement?

**My original question:**

I have a `DataGrid` in the content area of a `HeaderPanel`, but the detail lines in the `DataGrid` are not being displayed (the `DataGrid` column headings are showing, however). Is there an issue with using a `DataGrid` in the content area of a `HeaderPanel`? Or is this a simple misuse of the widgets? I'm adding the `HeaderPanel` to the `RootLayoutPanel`, which should provide the necessary resize notification (I think). Here is my UiBinder code:

```xml
<ui:UiBinder
  xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
  xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
  xmlns:c='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client'>
  <g:HeaderPanel>
    <g:SimplePanel/>
    <g:ResizeLayoutPanel>
      <c:DataGrid ui:field='dataGrid'/>
    </g:ResizeLayoutPanel>
    <g:HorizontalPanel>
      <g:Button
        ui:field='addRecordButton'
        text='Add Record'/>
      <g:Label ui:field='numberOfRecordsLabel'/>
    </g:HorizontalPanel>
  </g:HeaderPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

and here is the Java code:

```java
public class TempGWT implements EntryPoint {

@UiField
Button                    addRecordButton;
@UiField
DataGrid<Record>          dataGrid;
@UiField
Label                     numberOfRecordsLabel;

private ArrayList<Record> _recordList;

interface TempGWTBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, TempGWT> {
}

private static class Record {
private String _field1;
}

@Override
public void onModuleLoad() {
  _recordList = new ArrayList<Record>();
  TempGWTBinder binder = GWT.create(TempGWTBinder.class);
  Widget widget = binder.createAndBindUi(this);
  Column<Record, String> field1Column = new Column<Record, String>(new TextInputCell()) {
    @Override
    public String getValue(final Record record) {
      return record._field1;
    }
  };
  dataGrid.addColumn(field1Column, "Field 1");
  RootLayoutPanel.get().add(widget);
}

@UiHandler("addRecordButton")
public void onAddRecordButtonClick(final ClickEvent event) {
  Record record = new Record();
  record._field1 = "Record " + (_recordList.size() + 1);
  _recordList.add(record);
  dataGrid.setRowData(_recordList);
  numberOfRecordsLabel.setText("Records:" + _recordList.size());
}

}
```

I've attempted to trace the execution and, although I'm not certain, it looks as though the following happens when I change the size of the browser window and the "resize" request is received by the `DataGrid` (I've skipped some of the "unimportant" methods):

```
  DataGrid#onResize
  HeaderPanel#forceLayout
  ScrollPanel#onResize
```

The `DataGrid` object contains a `HeaderPanel`, which contains the headings for the `DataGrid` and a `ScrollPanel`. I don't know whether this is the key to the problem, but the `ScrollPanel` in the `DataGrid`'s `HeaderPanel` contains a `DataGrid$TableWidget` object, and `TableWidget` does not implement `RequiresResize`; the `ScrollPanel#onResize` method only sends the resize to its child if the child implements `RequiresResize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Tables and Frames` section of the [GWT Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels) makes it clear that I just needed to use a width/height of 100% for the DataGrid!  Like so:

```xml
  <c:DataGrid
    ui:field='dataGrid'
    width='100%'
    height='100%'/>
```